# How to load script tag only on specific page ? (Shopify)

Tags: shopify, script-tag

I am using PHP to add script tag to the storefront and wonder how to execute it only on a specific page such as the product page? Not on all storefront pages.

I'm adding like this:

```
    $script_array = array(
       'script_tag' => array(
       'event' => 'onload', 
       'src' => 'https://feeltrify.000webhostapp.com/scripts/shopify.js'
      )
   );

   $scriptTag = shopify_call($token, $shop, "/admin/api/2021-07/script_tags.json", $script_array, 'POST');
```

Comment: add an option to detect the product or specific page is JS code and executed it if the desired page extisted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific product template. Check this Shopify article on [how to create a template](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/templates#alternate-templates), You only need to create a new file on the template folder, let's say

```
custom-product-template.liquid
```

Copy and paste the product-template.liquid code (the main product template). Place your PHP code on the new template and assign this template to your desire product.

In order to assign a new template go to your Shopify Admin > Products > Select the product you wish to modify > change the template at the end of the sidebar section.

If you're working on a copy (not the live theme), it may happen that the template won't be available when selecting a product template on the admin product  page. Just create a file with the same name on the live theme and it should now be available.